# In React try to call function to delay using setTimeout

Tags: react-native

IN ReactNative I have created one loader and this loader show and hide using by function. But when I am trying to call this function in setTimeout this is not working it returns me error like this -> this.showLoader is not a function. is undefined. 
But when I am tried to without setTimeout it working fine.

```
export default class ThirdScreen extends Component<Props> {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    this.state = 
    {
       isLoading: false
    }
    this.showLoader = this.showLoader.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    setTimeout(function(){
      this.showLoader()
    }, 1000);
     //this.showLoader()
    }

    showLoader () {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    }

    hideLoader = () => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, this will solve your problem

```
setTimeout(()=> this.showLoader(), 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *showLoader()* function is declared inside *componentDidMount()* so it's not accessible via *this* pointer.